# In C#, why can't I pass a StringReader to a method with a Stream parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

In .net 4 and C#. I've implemented a static method to deserialize an XML stream into an object. This is only one xml format going into one object, so I'm not trying to do anything fancy with that. Since I can get this XML content in a variety of ways, I thought I'd make the parameter passed to the static method a Stream object. I'd thought that it would then take any object derived from base class Stream -- like FileStream, MemoryStream, StringReader, etc.

It works fine when I pass it a FileStream object, but not when I pass it a StringReader.

My static method:

```
    public static MatchObj DeserializeMatch(Stream srXml)
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MatchObj));
        MatchObj mObj = (MatchObj)xs.Deserialize(srXml);

        return mObj;
    }
```

It works with a FileStream:

```
        MatchObj objReply;
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("/App_Data/Match.xml"), FileMode.Open))
        { 
            objReply = MStatic.DeserializeMatch(fs);

            fs.Close();
        }
```

But not a StringReader:

```
StringReader sr = new StringReader(Request.Form["mXML"]);
MatchObj objReply = MStatic.DeserializeMatch(sr);
```

The build error is:  "cannot convert from 'System.IO.StringReader' to 'System.IO.Stream'"

Which in and of itself makes sense, but I thought that since StringReader implements TextReader, that it counted as Stream? XML Deserializer works fine with either.

I've worked around it simply by overloading that method to take a StringReader, but I hate to see what I thought was an elegant idea fall apart. Any ideas on why this doesn't work, and/or a way to make it work?

Comment: This may sound noobish from me.... but are you sure StringReader inherits from any kind of Stream?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the inheritance hierarchy of a StringReader...

```
System.Object 
  System.MarshalByRefObject
    System.IO.TextReader
      System.IO.StringReader
```

I would suggest putting Request.Form["mXML"] into a MemoryStream instead.

This might work (untested)...

```
var xmlBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Request.Form["mXML"]);
var ms = new MemoryStream(xmlBytes);
var reply = MStatic.DeserializeMatch(ms);
```

Comment: +1. I would suggest `var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sr.ReadToEnd()));` or skip the string-reader altogether with `var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Request.Form["mXML"]));`

Comment: I guess I had it stuck in my head that TextReader inherited from Stream. One of the things that kept me stuck on that was that XmlSerializer.Deserializer worked fine with either. I've since figured out that that method is simply overloaded, and besides Stream, can also take a TextReader or an XmlReader.

Comment: @Ani -- Tried your suggestion and it worked! I did: MatchObj objReply = MStatic.DeserializeMatch(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Request.Form["mXML"])));

Answer (score 4):

Well, technically, (but obviously) Because neither `StringReader` nor `TextReader` derive from `Stream`.
Perhaps more informatively, a `Stream` is the abstract base class that represents a sequence of Bytes.   All the `[Something]Reader` and `[Something]Writer` classes are designed to ***read*** or ***write*** to/from a `Stream`, they are not themselves `Stream` objects.  It is arguably true, however that these classes are all very poorly named and contribute to the misunderstanding that many developers have about this entire topic.

Comment: I think you're right about that. It just makes intuitive sense to me that something that can read or write to a stream would implement the Stream base class. But, I guess not!

Answer (score 1):

TextReader isn't a stream either, it inherits directly from MarshalByRefObject: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.aspx

Comment: It doesn't derrive from Stream.

Comment: The OP asserted "Which in and of itself makes sense, but I thought that since StringReader implements TextReader, that it counted as Stream?"

Comment: +1: hit the nail on the head: TextReader wouldn't work either, so the assumption by the OP that it does, is invalid.